# Rsyslog logging into /var/log/messages instead of custom file

Tags: linux, syslog

I have multiple perl daemons processes writing into a specific log file. In /etc/rsyslog.conf following is configuration -

```
    $ModLoad imuxsock
    $ModLoad imjournal
    $OmitLocalLogging off
    *.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local1.none     /var/log/messages
    local1.*           /var/log/logfilename.log
```

Multiple processes of the same deamon is run with different parameters.
What I have observed is that all the processes write to logfilename.log one of the process initially writes the data to logfilename.log after some time it just logs it in /var/log/messages file.

What could be the reason for rsyslog to stop logging into the custom file and write the log lines to /var/log/messages?

**Update:**
What we have observed is that if '*.info' is removed from the below line -

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local1.none     /var/log/messages
```

Then all the messages for local1 with priority info is logged properly in /var/log/logfilename.log file. 
Adding local1.none is not working here.